# Compare data in source sheet with target sheet and copy missing rows to target sheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Source sheet has 8 columns and target sheet has 9 columns (note first 8 columns are the same, the 9th column is used to set a url link once it has been mailed out). I don't want the target sheet to be sorted. The url link has to be on the appropriate row it pertains to.

This is the code I am working with so far. It does pull and compare the data, but it keeps adding a blank row at the beginning and after each run. I can't figure out why it does that?

```
function addNewStudents() {

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let source = ss.getSheetByName('Accepted Students')

  let sourceValues = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), 8).getValues().filter(String)
  //sourceValues.shift()
  //Logger.log(sourceValues)

  let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Confirmation Letters')
  let targetValues = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow(), 8).getValues().filter(String)

  //console.log(targetValues)

  let diff = targetValues.showDif(sourceValues)


  targetValues = (diff.length && diff) ? targetValues.concat(diff) : targetValues
  // console.log(targetValues)
  if (targetValues === '') {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    ui.alert("No new students")

  } else {
    targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues)
  }
  //console.log(targetValues.length)
}

Array.prototype.showDif = function (array) {
  let that = this;
  return array.filter(function (r) {
    return !that.some(function (x) {
      return r.join() === x.join()
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: There is no showDif method for arrays

Comment: Thanks @Cooper for your prompt response regarding showDif with arrays. As well, I still get a blank row either at the beginning or at the end of the copy. Changing this line target.getRange(1,1, target.getLastRow() - 1, 8).clearContent() to target.getRange(1,1, target.getLastRow(), 8), moves the blank row to the end of the list in the target sheet. Not sure why it adds a blank if there are no blank rows in the source sheet nor the target? Regardless, I can deal with a blank row at the end of the list. Thanks for your help on this matter. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Cooper That method is added in the code's last few lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the missing rows at the bottom of target sheet

```
function addNewStudents() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Accepted Students')
  const svs = ssh.getRange(2, 1, ssh.getLastRow(), 8).getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Confirmation Letters')
  const tvs = tsh.getRange(2, 1, tsh.getLastRow(), 8).getValues();
  let tA = tvs.map(r => r.join(""));
  svs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(!~tA.indexOf(r.join(""))) {
      tvs.push(r)
    }
  }); 
  tsh.getRange(2,1,tsh.getLastRow() - 1, tsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  tsh.getRange(2,1,tvs.length,tvs[0].length).setValues(tvs);
}
```

Comment: can you explain what the tilde symbol does in your if statement? I have never seen that before. Thanks again. Take care.

Comment: [Bitwise Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)  It's the same as writing tA.indexOf() != -1;